# (iOS)How to delete row when viewcontroller poped?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableView`. When I click on a row, it will push a detail view controller to show detail info.
And, if user clicks the "Done" button on the detail view controller, I need to pop this controller and delete row on tableview controller.

I try write code on detail view's `viewWillDisappear`:

```
if let vc = navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as? TodoViewController{
  vc.removeTodo(at:todoListIndex)
}
```

The code work fine, but just a warning:

> `UITableView` was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes.

So, What is the correct way to delete row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, it is there to remind you to avoid updating the view when it isn't visible. This typically happens when you update a view in a `viewWill____` state (in this case `viewWillDisappear`).

So what you want to do is delete the cell from TableView in `viewDid___` (such as `viewDidAppear`)lifecycle. Then, you will no longer see warning messages.

If needed, you can use help from `flag members` and `observables` to guide correct deletion timing.